# Type Checking in Mongoose Maps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have the following schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  modules: {
    type: Map,
    of: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Theoretically, mongoose should validate the type of each `UserModule` when I create a new document, ensuring the required `name` property is present.

However, if I create a user with a module without the `name` property:

```
await User.create({ modules: { example: {} } })
```

No error is thrown. Normally, mongoose is able to correctly validate for required types.

Workarounds I can think of include either hardcoding the keys for each module (and not use a map) or including a validator on the `modules` map to check all modules have the required keys are present, none of which are ideal.

Is there a better way to check the type of map values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are providing a value ... this is a valid [Map](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps) definition:

```
await User.create({ 
  modules: { 
    example: {}   // <-- this is a valid. Key is `example` value is {}
  } 
})
```

As far as [Map](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps) not having validation. Map does validate the **values** only since the keys are always strings. Consider this schema:

```
var AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  books: {
    type: Map,
    of: { type: Number },
    default: { "first book": 100 },  // <-- set default values
    required: true                   // <-- set required
  }
})

// after mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema) etc ....

var author1 = new Author({ books: { 'book one': 200 } })
author1.save() // <-- On save this works

var author2 = new Author({ books: { 'book one': "foo" } }) 
author2.save() // <-- This fails validation with "Cast to number failed ..."

var author1 = new Author()
author1.save() // <-- default would set values and that would pass the `required` validation
```

If you want to require the map make sure you do not have values in the default etc.

You can also review the `map` [tests @ github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/115ea98e91a2385fe16e3c819e8acb3609f4e28a/test/types.map.test.js) for more insight

And in those tests you can also see how to do a complex nested map:

```
var AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  pages: {
    type: Map,
    of: new mongoose.Schema({   // <-- just nest another schema
      foo: { type: Number },  // <-- set your type, default, required etc
      bar: { type: String, required: true } // <-- required!
    }, { _id: false }),
    default: { 
      'baz': { 
        foo: 100, bar: 'moo'  // <-- set your defaults
      } 
    }
  }
})
```

This would save as expected this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf1cf4b7f67711963e2406d"),
    "pages" : {
        "baz" : {
            "foo" : 100,
            "bar" : "moo"
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to save this would fail since `bar` is **required**:

```
var author = new Author({
  "pages" : {
    "baz" : { "foo" : 1 }  // <-- no bar!
  }
});
```

Comment: I thought of this, but this isn't really ideal considering I could change the schema for the `name` attribute in the future. In addition (not part of the question), but default values don't work either for map values, which is related to map values not having validation.

Comment: I think it works if the map values are a basic type like `Number`, `String`, etc., but if I try to strong type it with any object structure then it becomes problematic. For example, try it with `of: { type: { id: Number, name: String } }`.

Comment: The issue is that you're not meant to specify `of.type`, put the schema definition directly in `of`, i.e. `of: { id: Number, name: String }` or `of: { id: { type: Number, required: true }, name: { type: String, required: true }}`. Use [`#validate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate) or [`#validateSync`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validateSync) to validate the document.